# Read a localization string from a CustomAction in wix

Tags: localization, wix

I have a localizated wix project, and some custom actions in c#. Those custom actions sets some properties with customer facing text, so i want to assing a localizated text to those properties. Does any one know if i can read a localization string from a c# custom action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a Property to the localized string, and then access that Property from your Custom Action.  If your CA is deferred, then you will need to load the localized string into it's CustomActionData dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to avoid using a property to access a localized string since i have a lot of loc strings and this will pollute the code, but seems like there is no other alternative. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Bryan Batchelder's answer i was able to achieve this:

**.wxl localization file:**

```
<WixLocalization Culture="en-us" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
    <String Id="IISRequired">This application requires IIS.</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

**.wxs file:**

```
<Property Id="TXT_IIS_REQUIRED" Value="!(loc.IISRequired)"></Property>
```

**.cs Custom Action file:**

```
string str = session["TXT_IIS_REQUIRED"];
```

Comment: @erict, loc is a global object holding localized strings, so `!(loc.IISRequired)` refers to <String Id="IISRequired">. See more at https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/localized_extensions.html